# CICSCallable thread does not end

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, websphere-liberty, cics

I have a Java application that will run on a IBM Liberty application server; I'm trying to use multithreading with the `CICSExecutorService`. This is my use case:

1. create an instance of `CICSExecutorService`;
2. Create a thread (that makes a simple select query to the Db2) from a class that implements `CICSTransactionCallable`;
3. Submit the thread to the executor service;
4. Shutdown the executor service and wait for the termination;

This is the code:

```
    CICSExecutorService cicsExecutorService = new CICSExecutorService();
    //CICSReadingJob is the class that implements CICSTransactionCallable interface
    CICSReadingJob<String> thread1 = new CICSReadingJob<>();
    Future<List<String>> future1 = cicsExecutorService.submit(thread1);

    cicsExecutorService.shutdown();
    cicsExecutorService.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I have make some simple local tests with the standard java executor service and the behavior is that, after calling the shutdown and awaitTermination methods, the program waits for the threads termination (unless the execution of the threads takes more than 100 seconds, the specified timeout), and then the execution proceeds. The problem is that when I use the code above I see a different behavior: in fact, the program remains stuck on the `awaitTermination` row for 100 seconds also if the thread ( the only one connected with the `CICSExecutorService`) ends before (reaches the end of the `call()` method). I also try to use the static method `CICSExecutorService.runAsCICS()` instead of `cicsExecutorService.submit()`, but I obtain the same result. It seems that the child thread remains alive also when it reaches the end of the `call()` method, and for this reason the `awaitTermination` waits until the end of the timeout. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CICSExecutorService instance is already provided internally by CICS. It is accessed directly from the static API methods such as the runAsCICS() method. You do not (and should not) attempt to construct the ExecutorService, or control the ExecutorService yourself - that is all done internally to ensure the correct environment and life-cycles are observed. There is a public constructor on the class purely to comply with Declarative Services requisites and not for general use. It looks like the the Javadoc should be more explicit about the intended use - I'll see if I can get that updated.

This page provides more details on how to use the API (albeit for a Runnable rather than a Callable, but the API follows the same pattern):
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMCP_5.5.0/applications/developing/java/dfhpjgo.html

Note that you are submitting a 'Callable', not a thread, to the Executor. It is the CICSExecutorService which will decide in the background to run your callable on a 'CICS' enabled thread - allowing for thread pooling and re-use and other such smarts internally.

Also, if you are driving a CICS Liberty application, you should not usually need to spawn new CICS enabled threads yourself - the application will handle multiple, concurrent requests (typically web-requests) implicitly.

From the code snippet I cannot determine what your application is trying to achieve, but the Callable object which you submit should have it's call() method driven to completion, at which time the CICS task will end, and the thread on which it ran will be returned to the ExecutorService's thread-pool. The thread will remain dormant in that pool but no-longer associated with a CICS transaction (ready for re-use by another transaction). So if you are explicitly attempting to determine if the thread has terminated then you will be disappointed, they are not designed to terminate in the Liberty environment until the JVM server is disabled.

Typically when using the runAsCICS() method, you submit your Callable and get back a Future object. That Future object is then used to determine when the submitted work has completed. You should not attempt to wait for, or manipulate, the ExecutorService directly.

I hope that helps, but if you are still experiencing issues, please post more of the test-application and describe what you are trying to achieve so we can give better guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; so if I understand correctly everytime I nedd to use a new thread I must use the CICSExecutorService.runAsCics(); I can't "stop" the execution of the father thread to wait the termination of the children threads directly, but I should check the state of the Futures to undertstand if a thread is complete or not; is that correct?

Comment: Yes, if you need to spawn asynchronous operations on CICS enabled threads, beyond the concurrent multi-threaded capability of requests to a CICS JVM, then you should submit each piece of work with CICSExecutorService.runAsCICS(). Using the returned Future object, you can choose to 'wait' or 'poll' for completion in the father thread, or you can leave them to complete asynchronously. Both father and child operations will run on separate threads under separate CICS transactions and the father can complete before the children - or it can wait for one or more.

Comment: And how can I wait until every children is terminated (obviously without a while() with a list of futere.isDone )? I also can't find ( reading the documentation )  a way to add a callback to run when the thread finish ( something that return a CompletableFuture for example)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start a bunch of child threads as CICS tasks and wait until all children are terminated, you can also do this with the [CICS Async API](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg248411.html?Open). This also has a JCICS interface, and a set of samples are available on the CICSDev [GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=topic%3Aasynchronous-api%20org%3Acicsdev&type=Repositories)

Comment: Thank you for the response; unfortunately the red book and the Github examples almost only concern COBOL; there are few information about asynchronous operations in java.

Comment: I found this simple sample which illustrates the basic use case of starting a child transaction and fetching the result.
`AsyncService asyncServ = new AsyncServiceImpl();
Future<ChildResponse> childToken1 = asyncServ.runTransactionId("XXXX");
ChildResponse anyResponse = asyncServ.getAny();
if (anyResponse.equals(childToken1)) { msg = "Successfully fetched child token ";}
else {msg = "Failed to fetched child token ";}
`

Once you have fetched the result you can go on to get the returned Channel data using `ChildResponse.getChannel();`.